# How do I make a link to a line # with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, url, hyperlink, line

I made a program in Java to search through my workspace in the java files for a keyword. It then outputs (System.out.println) all the files in the workspace containing one or more instances of in in the format:

`Class #filename#.java in project #project# (#filename#.java:#line#)`

When Eclipse gets this, it automatically parses that last part in ()'s to a clickable link that takes you to that line of that file. I like this, but I want to make my program into a .jar file that doesn't need Eclipse, but I still want to make it so when you click the link it opens up that file at that line in Eclipse (It'll be in a JLabel instead of the log console). I could do this simply by opening the file in a java-made text editor, and shifting the caret-position, but I want to do it in Java.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to launch Eclipse from your application and make it open a file that you provide as a parameter, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a GUI you can add links to e.g. a JEditorPane in order to then open a file in question and go to the desired location in that file.

Comment: That's what I was saying I could do, open up a text editor I made with the line highlighted in it. But if possible, I want it to open in Eclipse with the line highlighted, like it does when you click the link in Eclipse's Log Console.